# When are the android prefixes necessary?

Tags: android

I understand that in Android anything I place in my res/ directory will get compiled into the appropriate R class:

```
res/drawable -> R.drawable
res/layout   -> R.layout
```

etc.

I know I can also use items that are in the android package:

```
android.R.id.text1
```

If I want to use my resources in xml I can do the following:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/my_text" />
```

If I want to use something in the android package I can do the following:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:id="@android:id/text1" />
```

This doesn't always seem to be the case and I cannot figure out the distinction.
When using AppCompat Themes:

```
<TextView
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />
```

instead of

```
<TextView
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />
```

Theme.AppCompat.Light and TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead are not defined anywhere in my res/ directory. They are included as part of the support.v7.appcompat support library. Why don't I need to use the android prefix in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are part of your app, not part of the framework. It's not that you don't need it; if you try it, you will get a compile error.

The fact that `appcompat-v7` happens to be a library is immaterial. It is no different than if you typed in the code yourself. Anything that is in your app does not use the `android` prefix. Resources that are part of the framework — and therefore are on the device, not in your app — get the `android` prefix.

Comment: So nothing in the support libraries ever uses the prefixes. Only things that are part of the target sdk?

Comment: @Dismissile: I would phrase it as "nothing *defined* in the support libraries use the prefixes". Just as your code can use framework resources, so can support libraries.